# Counting Fields in Database

Tags: mysql

When I run a statement to see how many rows for a specific date I get the following result - 3 rows
[image]

However because Table 9 has 2 different numbers at Five & Six and then at Eight & Nine I really need the result to come back as 4 rows like this

[image]

This is the code Im using

```
SELECT BookingDate, Table, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, TenID
FROM **** WHERE BookingDate = '2013-09-24'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: yeah thats what I want to do but for other dates it could be different times that could be different ie Six & Seven could be 3000 and Nine and Ten could be 3001

Comment: Can you be more explicit about this, i.e. give us a well-defined set circumstances under which you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate one row (i.e. there's only one such row in the input) where `Five` or `Six` is not `NULL` and `Eight` or `Nine` is not `NULL`, this should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  /* Select everything you want, one of each */
  SELECT BookingDate, `Table`, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, TenID
  FROM ...
  WHERE BookingDate = '2013-09-24'

  UNION ALL

  /* Select all rows that should be duplicated */
  SELECT BookingDate, `Table`, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, TenID
  FROM ...
  WHERE BookingDate = '2013-09-24'
    AND (Five  IS NOT NULL OR Six  IS NOT NULL)
    AND (Eight IS NOT NULL OR Nine IS NOT NULL)
) a
ORDER BY `Table`  /* or whatever you want to order by */
```

`Table` is a reserved word, that's why it needs to be in `` ` ``'s (in my personal opinion, you should preferably stay away from using reserved word as column / table names).

If this is not exactly what you want, I hope it will be enough to derive what you want.